# remove disabled attribute according input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function add_option(){
 var tot_option=parseInt($('#tot_option').val());
 tot_option++;
 $('#tot_option').val(tot_option);
 var par="'radio"+tot_option+"'";
 var opt="<input type='text' id='opt"+tot_option+"' onblur='chk(this.value,'"+par+"')' name='answers[]' style='width:80%;' onfocus='add_option()'> <input type='radio' id='radio"+tot_option+"' required disabled name='canswer' value='"+tot_option+"'><br><br>";
 document.querySelectorAll("input[onfocus]").forEach(function(element, index) {
      element.removeAttribute("onfocus");
   });
 $('#new_option').append(opt);
}
function chk(ivalue,rad){
 if(ivalue!=''){
  $('#'+rad).removeAttr('disabled');
 }else{
  $('#'+rad).attr('disabled','disabled');
  $('#'+rad).removeAttr('checked','checked');
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style='width:80%;' onblur="chk(this.value,'radio1')" id="opt1" name="answers[]">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" disabled required name="canswer" value="1"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="opt2" onblur="chk(this.value,'radio2')" style='width:80%;' name="answers[]" onfocus="add_option()">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" required disabled name="canswer" value="2"><br><br>
<span id="new_option"></span>
```

i have multiple input type and one radio button in front of every input i want to remove disabled from radio if my input type have some value if it has no value then add disabled attribute to radio. its working fine in first two input but after that its not working

Comment: try to use setAttribute() of javascript like $('#'+rad).setAttribute('disabled',false/true) for enable or disable the radio it might works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there were some flaws in your code,

1 you are sending this.value here as a string `onblur='chk(this.value,'"+par+"')`

2 in this `onblur function call` there is a problem while sending par as a parameter,

so here I Modified your code a bit and now this is working

```js
function add_option(){
    var tot_option=parseInt($('.totalOption').length);
    tot_option++;
    $('#tot_option').val(tot_option);
    var par="'radio"+tot_option+"'";
    var onBlur = 'onblur=chk('+ par.toString() +')';
    var opt="<input type='text' id='opt"+tot_option+"' class='totalOption' " + onBlur + " name='answers[]' style='width:80%;' onfocus='add_option()'> <input type='radio' id='radio"+tot_option+"' required disabled name='canswer' value='"+tot_option+"'><br><br>";
    document.querySelectorAll("input[onfocus]").forEach(function(element, index) {
            element.removeAttribute("onfocus");
    });
    $('#new_option').append(opt);
}
function chk(rad){
    if(event.relatedTarget == null)
        return;
    var SelctedTarget = Number(event.relatedTarget.id[event.relatedTarget.id.length - 1]) - 1;
    var ivalue = $('#opt' + SelctedTarget).val();
    if(ivalue!=''){
        $('#'+rad).removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
        $('#'+rad).attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#'+rad).removeAttr('checked','checked');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style='width:80%;' onblur="chk('radio1')" id="opt1" class="totalOption" name="answers[]">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" disabled required name="canswer" value="1"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="opt2" class="totalOption" onblur="chk('radio2')" style='width:80%;' name="answers[]" onfocus="add_option()">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" required disabled name="canswer" value="2"><br><br>
<span id="new_option"></span>
```